# Describe geometrically the set of points $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy $x + y = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Describe geometrically the set of points $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy $x + y = 2$

My guess here is: $(0,0,2)$

Prior to this question I had the following questions:

> Describe geometrically the set of points $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy $z = 4$

My answer is: $(0,0,4)$

> Describe geometrically the set of points $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy $y = −3$

My answer is: $(0,-3,0)$

I believe I'm answering these questions correctly, but I just want to make sure I'm on the right track.  It's been almost 2 years since I've done any calculus.

Comment: The question asks for the set of points. There are many more points that satisfy the requirements, you need to include them...

Comment: Does $(0,0,2)$ satisfy $x+y=2$ ?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I see now.

Comment: Just to give an idea of what you're missing: In the first case, you sure $(0,0,2)$ satisfies $x+y=2$? In the second case what about $(102, -78.5, 4)$ for example?

Comment: @hamedp so in example 2, would it just be $(x,y,4)$ and example three would be $(x,-3,z)$?

Comment: Yep. Exactly :)

Comment: @hamedp thanks!  I'm not sure how to apply this same logic to $x+y=2$.  Is this like adding two vectors and it forming a new vector?

Comment: Try drawing $x+y=2$ in $x$-$y$ plane, what are the points? Also look at the answer already given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a plane with normal vector $(1, 1, 0)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I guess there is something I'm still not "seeing" with your answer.  For example, is another answer also $(5,-3,0)$?

Comment: $(5, -3, 0)$ is a point of plane $x+y=2$ and $(1,1, 0)$ is a normal vector to plane.